# how to run 1 Express server project multiple time and with diferent .env file

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, content-management-system, server-side-rendering

I created a headless CMS project that can have different uses, now I run 2 websites on 1 server but in order to do I have 2 different folders with the same project and the only difference between them is the .env file which holds databases name, ports, and all the required data. this will cause performance usage of the server.

now I wanna run 1 express server project multiple times with different .env files. I know that we can run the server by changing 1 variable in .env like ("NODE_ENV=production node ./server.js") but I want to run the project with a totally different .env file, so in the folder, I will have .env1 .env2 .env3 and so when I run the project it run multiple time on multiple ports with multiple databases and finally I can run several websites at the same time by only 1 project.

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use `dotenv`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

You can specify which .env file path to use via the path option with something like this:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` })
```

Then run your script with that the right environment variable to get the right `.env` file.

You can change the `path` as you want, as long as it points to the right path for the right file.

Edit 1:

https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd

For CLI level solution, you could use this.

`npm install -g env-cmd`

Then in your `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "server": "env-cmd ./env1 node index.js",
    "server2": "env-cmd ./env2 node index.js",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, already I am using dotenv ,is there any way on the run-script command we use this? I can not add some specific file to the source code, as I said this is headless multiple propose CMS project so I need to think about every single possibility

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, you want `dotenv` to load the right env file just by configuration at CLI as argument?

Comment: sort of, I wanna run 1 server multiple time on multiple ports so I need to set different DB and port which identify the site, now I have the same project in 3 folders and the only difference is .env file and when I wanna update them I have to do it 3 times and it causes an issue on the server performance